# Displaying unique file name with File name and NSDateString as TableView titles (need help)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

In my iOS app project, I create recorded audio.caf files saved in the documents directory file structure,  which are then to be displayed as an array, listed in consecutive TableViewCells of the TableView. 
I want show both the unique “audio file name” and “NSDate” of the files created as a title
and subtitle consecutively , within each cell.
The code used to create the recorded file at a given path is in the Mainviewcontroller.

```
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                                   _filePath,
                                   nil];
        newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents: pathComponents];
        _filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio %@ %@.caf"];
        // Initiate and prepare the recorder
        //NSInteger count = 0;
// To create the date string <---
        NSString *dateString;
        NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate];
        NSLog(@"datestring %@",dateString);


        int count = 0;
        int arrayCount = [audioFileArray count];



            documentsDirectory = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:0];

            NSError *error = nil;
// To create the recorded file name and date combined <---
            _audioFileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
            filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"audio %@ %@.caf", dateString,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[_audioFileArray count]]];
                    count ++;
```

I also want to re-arrange the code so the file "number" comes before the "NSDate", but this is the only way that it works ie; DateString before the _audioFileArray count bit!

And, in the UITableView fileViewController the bit that displays the filenames text is:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"simpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
NSString *name = [_filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//add the text display that is drawn from the array list
cell.textLabel.text = name;
cell.textLabel.text = [_filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is the recorded date", name];
return cell
```

The titles of my array, displayed in the UITableViewCells are shown in this illustration.

[Table view cells comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MPrR.gif)

What I am looking to do is remove the date (created) part of the title in each cell and relocate that in the detailtextLabel title instead.
I could do this maybe by creating a separate NSDate class that can be called (or utilised) by the main view controller and the detail view controller
simultaneously, but I however haven’t been successful in trying this approach yet.

for instance, would this work better instead by using a JSON or plist to create a dictionary for each saved files properties.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and if this post needs more clarity, please let me know also.

Lastly, I have searched long and wide on the forums for a concise solution to this problem, and have not found a fix, as yet.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i saw your code, it seems that the date string return nil or empty value.
replace your code:

```
NSString *dateString;
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate];
NSLog(@"datestring %@",dateString);
```

with this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"datestring %@",dateString);
```

Thank you..

Comment: @Somme. getting back to your earlier submission. The NSDate formatter I hacked together in my example actually returns a date string. That is, when it sits in Mainviewcontroller and in the scope of the audio file creation class. However, when I move it out of this Main file and make it as a separate NSDate class, that’s where I have trouble with it being called.

Comment: So, for now it sits in this view controller just to perform a service.
My main problem though is that I need to parse the string of the file name (saved with unique file sequence number and formatted date), and represent this in the Table
View cells as main title and detail text subtitle, displaying the formatted date. (check my image link above to show how it needs to work)
Again, if can successfully create a NSDate class/ file that all the Viewcontrollers can call on, this may even give me some success.
(nI hope this post is not too ambiguous)
Any feed back appreciated